# get a string from user and put its charater in 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

i want to make user input a String and i want to take its character in 2d array
First user input the size of array its n*n array so if user input `4` for example he make array 4*4 2d and i want to print the input as he input my code

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=in.nextInt();
char arr[][]=new char[n][n];
String a;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a=in.next(); //Eneter the sting 
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
    {
        for (int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            arr[j][k]=a.charAt(j); //i get the character in the array
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr)); //to check the array
```

if user input

```
4
...#
.#.#
.#..
####
```

the output

```
[[#, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #], [#, #, #, #]]
```

Expected out put as user input

```
[[., ., ., #], [., #, ., #], [., #, ., .], [#, #, #, #]]
```

i just begin java from 2 days and 2d array iam not good in it
How to fill This in 2d array as i Expected
Last thing i want to print the index of each # in the array such as in first row it found in  `1 4` in second row found in `2 2`   `2 3` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too many loops,  here is your modified code :

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        char arr[][] = new char[n][n];
        String a;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a = in.next(); //Eneter the sting

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {

                arr[i][k] = a.charAt(k); //i get the character in the array
            }

        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));

// print indexes
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

                System.out.println("Line " + i);

                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {

                    if (arr[i][k] == '#') {
// (print i+1 and k+1 instead of i and k, if you prefer)
                        System.out.print(i + " " + k);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();

            }
```

Comment: last thing what about to get the index that i refer in question this last thing and maaaaaaany thanks

Comment: can you write the code please how to do this and thank you

Comment: I've just added a loop for indexes

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
it will work !!

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();
    char arr[][]=new char[n][n];
    String a;
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a = in.next();
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=a.charAt(j);             
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
```

Comment: works great but what about the index i refer at the end of my Qu and thank you